# How to execute datapump commands as sysdba from remote machine

Tags: oracle, data-pump

I would like to know the syntax to call datapump commands (expdp/impdp) logged as 'sys as sysdba' from a remote machine.

I know that when logged on the machine which runs the database, I can use :

```
expdp \"/ as sysdba\"
```

However, I cannot find how to do this from a remote machine, for example, these does not work :

```
expdp 'SYS@SID AS SYSDBA'
expdp "SYS AS SYSDBA"@SID
```

In both case, the error message is :

```
LRM-00108: invalid positional parameter value [...]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
expdp \"SYS@service AS SYSDBA\"
```

This works for me (10.2 and 11.1), but you need either to define service in your tnsnames.ora or to use proper SCAN. Generally, ORACLE_SID is a different identifier than TNS service, but for simplicity they often are administratively set to the same value.

Comment: Dear future readers: Using the `user/pass@db_link` format in the login may lead to a `UDE-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version` message.  To work around this, supply the database link via the `NETWORK_LINK` parameter instead.

Comment: as a note to everyone, please note the escaping of the double quotation marks. the backslashes fixed the problem for me

Comment: wow, how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

I use IMPDMP as follows:

`Impdp SYS@SYSDBA/45561602 SCHEMAS=PRUEBAS DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=PRUEBAS.dmp remap_schema=PRUEBAS:TEST TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace LOGFILE=impdmp.log`